# Cultish birthday puzzle

Tags: probability, birthday

I was asked the following puzzle recently which I couldn't see how to solve.

A particular cult wants to find a group of people all of whom have different birthdays for some mysterious ceremony they are about to hold. However all they require in order to be quorate is to have in this group one person whose birthday is on Christmas day and one whose birthday is on the day Easter Sunday falls this year.  They invite people into a room with $10$ chairs one at a time.  If the person who comes in has the same birthday as anyone else in the room (not including the hosts) they are told to sit down. Otherwise they stay in the room standing up as part of the selected group.  What are the chances they can get their group before all the chairs are full?

Comment: So you need an odd number of people born on Christmas and an odd number of people born on Easter, right?

Comment: You just need exactly one of each in the standing group. As soon as you have that, they have their group.

Comment: I mean you don't need to worry about sitting/standing - just ask whether an odd number of the people who arrive are born on Christmas and Easter, respectively. The sum would probably be easier to calculate if $d$ is even..

Comment: Wait - "not including the hosts". That means you really just need one on Christmas and one on Easter.

Comment: Do we include February 29th as a valid birthday?  Should we account for the fact that it occurs 97/400 as frequently as other days?

Comment: You can assume the number of days in the year is $365$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p(n,d,k)$ be the probability of succeding if the starting position is a group of $n$ standing people (with different birthdays), $d$ chairs still available and $k$ special dates still needed to cover.
By convention, $p(n,d,k)=0$ if $d<0$.

We are looking for $p(0,d,2)$.

Clearly, $p(n,d,0)=1$ for any $n,d\ge0$.

To compoute $p(n,d,k)$ for $n,d\ge 0$, $k>0$, note that the next candidate hits one of the special days with $\frac k{365}$, needs a chair with $\frac n{365}$ and increases the group otherwise.
Therefore,
$$ p(n,d,k) = \frac k{365}p(n+1,d,k-1) + \frac n{365}p(n,d-1,k) + \frac{365-k-n}{365}p(n+1,d,k).$$
This allows us to compute the values recursively (note that one never needs to compute cases with $n+k>365$).

**EDIT:** Some specific value:
$p(0,10,2)\approx 0.050811782658608833417260473067490416381$

Comment: What is the actual answer $p(0, 10, 2)$? Also, your second term is probably wrong: shouldn't it be $(n+d)/365$, since anyone who shares birthdays with someone already seated also sits down?

Comment: The asnwer should be $p(0,10,2)$, not $p(0,10,0)$. Also, if you share  birthday with someone seated, you also shore it with someone standing, so %\fracn{365}$ is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I think the $p(0, 10, 2)$ is something I fixed while you were typing your comment; the other one was truly a mistake. Thanks.